# Can't get linear-gradient to work on particular SquareSpace template

Tags: css, linear-gradients, squarespace

I am trying to adjust the background-color property for the header with an id of header.

```
<header id="header" class="sqs-announcement-bar-dropzone">
```

The color can accept solid values without a problem, but when I try to run any linear-gradient function I receive an error message 'Invalid property value'.

Here's an example linear-gradient function:

```
linear-gradient(blue, black)
```

I've tested this on another SquareSpace site I have and it has no problems accepting linear-gradient functions.

This is the URL of the site in question: https://anthony-mayfield-tdr0.squarespace.com/#new-page

Can anyone see the problem?

Comment: The site in question does not actually have anything with an id of header.

Comment: For sure it does. The header contains the entire navbar. It's contained within the div class .site-wrapper.

Comment: Oh, you wanted me to click the "visitor access" button first. That wasn't very clear; you should have mentioned that. Also, the stylesheet is huge; could you paste just the offending parts here in your message or in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Design Panel > to > Custom CSS pane:

```
body.fixed-header #header {
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) linear-gradient(#2a4c9e, #000000) repeat scroll 0 0; }
```

You need to call the hex color specifically as well as use the correct *selector* syntax.

Hope this helps. If so, please select it as the correct answer here as well.